# Django media image not showing up in template but can acces it via .../media/thumbnail/image.png

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Altough context does render in html, i can use other variables but cant accsess the image. My code is:

html:

```
    {% for a in Manga %}
        <div class="manga_container">
            <div class="manga_image">
                <p>{{a.manga_image}}</p>
                <img src="{{ x.manga_image.url }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    {%endfor%}
```

model:

```
class Manga(models.Model):
    manga_name = models.CharField(max_length= 255, default="null")
    manga_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="thumbnail", default="thumbnail/noimage.png")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}, {self.manga_name}"
```

and lastly view:

```
def Index(request):
    manga = Manga.objects.all().values()
    chapter = Chapter.objects.all().values()
    fansub = Fansub.objects.all().values()

    context= {
        "Manga": manga,
        "Chapter": chapter,
        "Fansub": fansub,
    }

    template = loader.get_template("Index.html")

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

ı have used function based views since ı have to deal with multiple models at once.

my media and url is as following:

```
import os

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have put that p tag for me to see its url and as you can see it  was in the right place, when i go to 127.0.0.1:8000/media/thumbnail/noimage.png i can see it and it does come up to my screen. i have tried most of the ways i could have think of. I want to see the image on my html and i didnt touch anything so it is basicly default image as i have configured it to.

Comment: Variable name as `a`, not `x`. Typo here: `{{ x.manga_image.url }}`

Comment: Oops i have accidenty changed it while copy pasting the original is using all a as variables my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Manga.objects.all().values()
```

Use:

```
Manga.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it did work but can you please explain the logic about what is going on here and how it eorks

Comment: @PlatinMavi Since [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) returns dictionaries rather than model instances, see the link.